# how to check the result is multiples (python)?

Tags: python, math, conditional-statements

I have this assignment and I'm very newbie to mathematic and python. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Complete this function that prints the integers from 1 to 100 (inclusive).

> 1)  For numbers that are multiples of three print "Fizz" instead of
>   the number
>
> 2)  For numbers that are multiples of five print "Buzz" instead of the
>   number and
>
> 3)  For numbers that are multiples of both three and five  print
>   "FizzBuzz" instead of the number

I tried this:

```
x=1
while x <= 100:


    if x/3 ==int and x/5 ==int:
        print ("FizzBuzz")
    elif x/3 == int:
        print("Fizz")
    elif x/5 == int:
        print("Buzz")
    else:
        print(x)
    x=x+1
```

and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modulo operator returns remainder, so all you have to check that if remainder of `x` divided by `3` or `5` is equal to 0. so

Use `%` modulas operator.

```
if x%3 == 0 and x%5 == 0:  
    print ("FizzBuzz")

elif x%3 == 0 :
        print("Fizz")
elif x%5 == 0 :
        print("Buzz")
```

or use `not` operator

```
if not x%3 and not x%5:
    print ("FizzBuzz")
```

as `30%3` is `0` and `not 30%3` is `True`.

or use `all()` builtin function.

all: (iterable)
│all(iterable) -> bool
│
│Return True if bool(x) is True for all values x in the

```
 if not all([x%3, x%5]):
    print ("FizzBuzz")
```

Comment: That's better, but I think your 2nd & 3rd code blocks may be a bit confusing. And please fix the spelling of the name of the operator it's `modulo` or sometimes `modulus`; the Python docs use the first form.

Answer (score 1):

```
for num in range(1,101):
    if num%3==0 and num%5==0:
        print("FizzBuzz")

    elif num%3==0:
        print("Fizz")

    elif num%5==0:      
        print("Buzz")

    else:
        print(num)
```

Here `%` is the modulo operator that returns a remainder. 
A multiple of 3 has remainder of 0 when divided by 3 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is fine, but your Python syntax is faulty. Others have shown you how to do what you want using the modulo operator `%`. So I'll tell you why the code you posted doesn't work.

In Python 3, when you use the `/` operator the result is *always* a `float` (a floating-point number), even if the answer can be expressed as an integer; to force Python to use integer division on integer values you use the `//` operator. So simply performing a division and then testing if the type of the result is `int` isn't helpful.

It is possible to use the `int` keyword to test if an object is an integer, but the syntax needed to do that is a little different to what you wrote. The proper syntax is like

```
a = 5
isinstance(5, int)
```

or

```
a = 5
type(a) is int
```

The first form is preferred.

The keyword `int` actually creates a `type` object. As you probably know you can call it as a function to convert an object to an integer, eg `int('5')` converts the string `'5'` to the integer `5`. But you should type `int` into the interpreter on a line by itself and see what gets printed.